# Understanding the linker scripts for STM32F103C8T6

Tags: linker, firmware, bare-metal, linker-scripts

I have recently got into STM32F103C8T6 bare-metal programming, and the linker script implementation seems a little confusing. I found two versions of linker scripts online, and surprisingly both work as expected, despite the huge difference in their contents.

**Version 1**, as used [here](https://jacobmossberg.se/posts/2017/01/10/minimalistic-assembler-program-on-stm32-h103.html)

```
SECTIONS
{
    .  = 0x0;         /* From 0x00000000 */
    .text : 
    {
        *(isr_vector) /* Interrupt Service Routine Vector table */
        *(.text)      /* Program code */
    }
}
```

and the resulting firmware is flashed with `flash write_bank 0 add.bin 0`

**Version 2**, as used [here](https://github.com/jasLogic/bare-metal-arm/tree/master/4_first_program_and_linker)

```
MEMORY {
    FLASH (rw): ORIGIN = 0x8000000, LENGTH = 64K
    RAM (rwx): ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 20K
}

ENTRY(Reset_Handler)
SECTIONS
{   .text : {
        KEEP(* (.isr_vector))
        * (.text*)
    } > FLASH

    __StackTop = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM);
}
```

and the resulting firmware is flashed with `flash write_image erase main.bin 0x8000000`

As you can see, in both linker script and the OpenOCD command to flash the firmware, version 1 flashes `.text` to `0x00000000`, whereas version 2 flashes to `0x8000000`. Firstly, I'm not sure what these addresses refer to: are they LMA or VMA? Secondly, why does flashing to different addresses have the same effect?

I did some research, but the [Programming manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/programming_manual/5b/ca/8d/83/56/7f/40/08/CD00228163.pdf/files/CD00228163.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00228163.pdf) doesn't seem to address my confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The processor boots looking for a vector table at address 0x00000000 in arms address space.  ST has implemented their part such that application flash is at address 0x08000000 in the arms address space.

Depending on the boot mode ST can if you will mirror either the built in bootloader program to address 0x00000000 or the application.  Such that arm accesses to address 0x00000000 will return with values found in a flash.  If mirroring the application then both 0x00000000 and 0x08000000 will read values from the same physical flash device and return them.  There is no magic here, the ARM bus has an address and amount of data it wants to read, the logic has masks and matches to determine which address space it is, then if 0x00000000 to some number of Kbytes, then if strap is one way read from one flash bank else read from another.  Likewise with writes.

Search for BOOT0 in the reference manual for the part.

Ideally you want to link for 0x08000000 (or 0x00200000 for some of the parts but not all) so that the vector table entries read at 0x00000004, 0x00000008 and so on return 0x0800xxxx addresses, that way only the vector table is actually read from 0x00000000 and then the rest of the program in the application address space.  You will see in the docs that the 0x00000000 address space for parts with a lot of flash does not support the whole size of the flash so you couldnt use all of the flash if you link for 0x00000000

now these linker scripts are interesting, first off if you see this in a vector table for a cortex-m

```
.word       _start + 1
.word       _nmi_handler + 1
.word       _hard_fault + 1
```

find another example.

```
.thumb

.section isr_vector
.word 0x20001000
.word one
.word two

.text
.thumb_func
one:
    b one
.thumb_func
two:
    b two
.thumb_func
```

First linker script

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <one-0xc>:
   0:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
   4:   0000000d    andeq   r0, r0, sp
   8:   0000000f    andeq   r0, r0, pc

0000000c <one>:
   c:   e7fe        b.n c <one>

0000000e <two>:
   e:   e7fe        b.n e <two>
```

in this case when the arm does a read of the vector table to find the reset vector at address 0x00000004 the ST part will return the value in the second word of the application flash (think address 0x08000004)

in this case it finds 0000000d which means start fetching instructions at address 0x0000000c.

With the second linker script

```
.thumb

.section .isr_vector
.globl _isr_vector
_isr_vector:
.word 0x20001000
.word Reset_Handler

.text
.globl Reset_Handler
.thumb_func
Reset_Handler:
    b .


Disassembly of section .text:

08000000 <_isr_vector>:
 8000000:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
 8000004:   08000009    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r3}

08000008 <Reset_Handler>:
 8000008:   e7fe        b.n 8000008 <Reset_Handler>
```

In this case when the arm looks for the reset vector at 0x00000004 it will get 0x08000009 which means fetch the first instructions at address 0x08000008 which is in the address space for the part for the application flash, this is preferred.

You will find some ST parts have a small window at 0x00200000 that can read some of that flash faster (its an arm thing ITCM vs AXIM, read the cortex-m7 docs).

By an msp432 and I think application flash is 0x01000000 same mirroring thing, just a different address.

```
.thumb_func
.align  2
.global Reset_Handler
.type   Reset_Handler, %function
Reset_Handler:
```

note in the second example the author has extra code, both .thumb_func and the .type mark that label as a function (which does the ORR with 1 to set the lsbit of the address so you don't have to have the ugly vector table, use the tools)

For example:

```
.thumb

.section .isr_vector
.globl _isr_vector
_isr_vector:
.word 0x20001000
.word Reset_Handler
.word Something_Else

.text
.globl Reset_Handler
.thumb_func
Reset_Handler:
    b .

.type Something_Else, %function
Something_Else:
    b .
    

Disassembly of section .text:

08000000 <_isr_vector>:
 8000000:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
 8000004:   0800000d    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r2, r3}
 8000008:   0800000f    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r2, r3}

0800000c <Reset_Handler>:
 800000c:   e7fe        b.n 800000c <Reset_Handler>

0800000e <Something_Else>:
 800000e:   e7fe        b.n 800000e <Something_Else>
```

both worked, which one you use is your personal preference

```
.thumb_func
```

is clean and simple and doesn't require matching the label, but it is position dependent, the next label is the one that is marked as a function.  Also there is no .arm_func

```
.type labelname, %function
```

works for both arm and thumb code it is arguably a little more typing and you have to match the label name, but there are pros to that as you clearly are stating the label you want to be identified as a function address and this habit works for both arm and thumb modes.

Both authors (or is it the same person twice?) have created unnecessary work.

Consider these

so.s

```
.thumb
.word 0x20001000
.word one
.word two

.thumb_func
one:
    b .

.thumb_func
two:
    b .
```

next.s

```
add r1,r2,r3
add r2,r3,r4
add r3,r4,r5
```

so.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    xyz : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > xyz
}

arm-none-eabi-as so.s -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-as next.s -o next.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -T so.ld so.o next.o -o so.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.elf

so.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

08000000 <one-0xc>:
 8000000:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
 8000004:   0800000d    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r2, r3}
 8000008:   0800000f    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r2, r3}

0800000c <one>:
 800000c:   e7fe        b.n 800000c <one>

0800000e <two>:
 800000e:   e7fe        b.n 800000e <two>
 8000010:   e0821003    add r1, r2, r3
 8000014:   e0832004    add r2, r3, r4
 8000018:   e0843005    add r3, r4, r5
```

That's good, but if you

```
arm-none-eabi-ld -T so.ld next.o so.o -o so.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.elf

so.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

08000000 <one-0x18>:
 8000000:   e0821003    add r1, r2, r3
 8000004:   e0832004    add r2, r3, r4
 8000008:   e0843005    add r3, r4, r5
 800000c:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
 8000010:   08000019    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r3, r4}
 8000014:   0800001b    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r3, r4}

08000018 <one>:
 8000018:   e7fe        b.n 8000018 <one>

0800001a <two>:
 800001a:   e7fe        b.n 800001a <two>
```

that's bad.

if not called out in the linker script then the command line position of the link determines order of the .text items in the file.  When providing an example or making a project shouldn't you have a makefile or build instructions to go with the code?  Do you really need to do the extra work in the linker script?  YMMV.

Also note the memory labels in the linker script are just labels to connect the dots between MEMORY and SECTIONS.  You can use whatever strings you want within limits and with some exceptions.

I used to use the (rw) stuff but it became problematic had to re-architect my less is more linker script between two versions of binutils. (looks to me like that example has a bug in it)  If the linker complains about a missing section (.rodata) just add it.

The beauty of bare metal is you are free to choose how you want to do this, unless you use libraries then you have to play in their sandbox.  And often you will find over engineered linker scripts and bootstraps and such trying to cover all kinds of possible use cases and features.  Just make one that covers your use case.

You can write your code such that you don't need to zero .bss nor copy .data, or you can choose to support .data but not .bss or you can fully support both with a relatively simple linker script and bootstrap.  You own the space on this mcu do you really need to design the stack into the linker script?  You know how big the part is just make the stack come down from the top. (granted you only need to type the size in once if you do the linker magic)  Your choice.  If you want to support a heap for some reason (why would you ever have a heap on an mcu? not a good thing) you can add that into the linker script too.

Again the beauty of bare-metal, so long as it works you are free to do whatever you want.  I recommend going beyond what these folks have done and learn the tools a little better (primarily on the assembly language side) so that you have more choices as to how you do it.

Why both work is because the part mirrors some/all of the 0x08000000 arm address space to 0x00000000.  so linking for either will work within the window.

You can choose what to label these I use the term arm address space, I would also use the term physical address, few if any of these cores have virtual memory space, so that wouldn't make sense.  The ARM bus from the ARM IP (arm does not make chips it makes cores that companies like ST buy and put their own or other folks logic around to make a chip) will send out a read with one of these physical addresses on it, how the chip responds is based on how they designed it.  The vector table entries are at known addresses meaning the logic is going to use a known address to read each item, and the chip and the programmer need to respond, if there were an mmu that could change the address space, the vector table would still need to be at one of those physical addresses if the handler logic went through the mmu.

So given the multiple choice test I would say Logical Memory Address, LMA.

The next thing here is that openocd supports writes to 0x00000000.  openocd supporting flash writes at all is a bonus as it is chip specific and someone has to put in the time.  Because of the nature of 0x00000000 for these parts and how you powered it up (strap pins) you could have it strapped wrong, and/or the openocd implementation has an assumption or a definition to always turn 0x00000000 into 0x08000000 or something like that, might be in the .cfg file itself which I looked at for you recently but didn't look for this detail.

Comment: Thanks sir, your answer is extremely detailed and educational to read! I am just a little curious about the `RAM (rwx): ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 20K` part: is it also some kind of mirroring from storage components by ST to the ARM address space? And the only difference between RAM and the flash is that RAM is volatile and be read/written faster?

Comment: Also about the OpenOCD part: are you suggesting that writing to 0x00000000 is based on an assumption about this specific chip, and thus in general (when working with chips in the wild) we should always look up its document for chip-specific addresses like `0x08000000`?

Comment: Just one last thing: You said "...  that way only the vector table is actually read from 0x00000000 and then the rest of the program in the application address space". I'm a little confused about the vector table **in the ARM address space** at `0x00000000` and "the rest of the program" **in the application address space** at `0x08000000`. What's the difference between the two address spaces? Since both go to the `.text` section, I expected they to appear in the same address space...

Comment: from the arms perspective when it does a read on its data bus at address 0x00000000 and a read from 0x08000000 these are two different addresses, two different address spaces.  Those different addresses are on the bus.  it is this specific chip that makes them answer with the same values.  the arm doesnt know or expect that, its we the programmer that knows that and further we know that the full size of the flash is only visible starting at 0x08000000.  we and arm know that the vector table will be accessed at 0x00000000 so we put these two pieces of information together.

Comment: with openocd you get what you get.  Access to the flash is very much chip/design specific it is not like the old days (wont get into that) so someone has to have taken the time to add code to openocd specifically for that flash controller on that chip (or family of chips) and submitted and had it approved in the mainline source for openocd.  whatever that/those developers chose to support is what is in there, you get what you get.  Assume with openocd there is no flash support, if there happens to be then thats a bonus, how to use it or not is an adventure.

Comment: If there is no flash support directly through openocd, but the chip supports in application programming then I will tend to write a program that I load into ram with openocd that my program writes the flash and through one or another way I get the data into that program that I want to write to the flash, either I embed the program to be written as data in the program that writes the flash, or make a bootloader and through the uart most likely will have a protocol/solution to send chunks of data to that program which then writes it.

Comment: for this/these parts from the documentation from ST the application flash begins at arm address 0x08000000, the sram at 0x20000000.  What that second example you posted is doing is doing the extra/unnecessary work for the vector table and .text.  it relies on the r and w in the RAM (rwx) for .data and .bss but I think there is a bug in their approach, didnt bother testing that thought independent of that they are using that RAM address and size line to create the __StackTop variable that would then be references in the boot code or vector table itself (first entry).

Comment: If you are struggling with linker scripts like these I recommend that you go with something simpler like the ones I have shown or start with ones like I have shown and very slowly add one component at a time to see how it affects the linker script while also reading from the gnu binutils documentation as to what that item does for a linker script.  it is a whole programming language of itself so if you want to know what each part does you have to learn it like a new programming language.

Comment: IMO that interferes with learning how to program the chip or making the arm work then programming the chip (the arm itself is but a tiny almost insignificant part of what you have to learn to program one of these chips its is to the chip as the english alphabet is to this conversation, relevant but in the background its the words and their groupings and meanings that carry the most weight here).  you dont NEED a fancy linker script, but to move forward you do need to learn how to access and control the peripherals.

Comment: At the same time this world of baremetal has a lot of things to learn and some folks rightly so want to learn it all.  My preference is to have a certain number of "wins", to keep confident and motivated, if it is endless failures then I tend to give up.  If I cant program the flash then can I put a program in ram and run it?  Can I make another program that I load into ram that blinks an led and so on, worrying about the flash at some other point in the future. Do I have to battle the tools right now to learn something new about them or can I make progress with what I know?  etc, etc.  YMMV

Comment: You are a scholar and a gentleman! Thanks so much for the information and advice. This will help me *a lot*, both in the short-term and in the long-term.

Comment: good luck, dont give up need more folks that understand this, but also have fun doing it...